# Найти два минимальных положительных элемента в матрице

Tags: массивы, pascal, матрицы

Знаю, как найти с помощью дополнительного массива и сортировки, но нужна другая реализация.

Answer (score 1):

А нечто в таком духе не подойдет? Банально наплевать на многомерность массива и идти по нему линейно.

```
m1 := 0; m2 := 0; { 0 — специальное значение, означающее «еще не нашли» }
for i := 1 to 3 do
  for j := 1 to 3 do
    if m[i, j] > 0 then
      { Или если мы еще не нашли ни одного положительного числа (m1 <= 0),
        или если текущее значение меньше самого малого (m1) }
      if m1 <= 0 or m[i, j] < m1 then
        m1 := m[i, j]
      { Если мы не нашли второго положительного числа (m2 <= 0),
        или если текущее значение больше либо равно m1, но меньше второго
        по порядку наименьшего (m2) }
      else if m2 <= 0 or m[i, j] < m2 then
        m2 := m[i, j];
```

Для простоты индексы я не запоминаю. Если не будет достаточного числа положительных чисел — `m2` (и, возможно, и `m1`) будут равны нулю. Если будет два одинаковых наименьших — на одном отработает ветка `m1`, на другом `m1` уже будет не меньше, и отработает `m2`.

Код писался на коленке, без тестирования, возможны опечатки.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм:

1. Инициализировать **a** и **b** значением равным наибольшему возможному целому.
2. Последовательно пройти по всем элементам матрицы в любом порядке.
3. Если текущий элемент меньше, чем **a**, то обновить **a** и **b**.
4. Иначе если текущий элемент меньше, чем **b**, обновить **b**.
5. Вывести **a** и **b**.

Сложность - O(n).